# python pandas incorrectly reading excel dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with dates formatted as such:

```
22.10.07 16:00
22.10.07 17:00
22.10.07 18:00
22.10.07 19:00
```

After using the parse method of pandas to read the data, the dates are read *almost* correctly:

```
In [55]: nts.data['Tid'][10000:10005]
Out[55]:
10000    2007-10-22 15:59:59.997905
10001    2007-10-22 16:59:59.997904
10002    2007-10-22 17:59:59.997904
10003    2007-10-22 18:59:59.997904
```

What do I need to do to either a) get it to work correctly, or b) is there a trick to fix this easily? (e.g. some kind of 'round' function for datetime)

Comment: Current fix: create a new time vector:                                    time = [t0 + dt.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(len(nts.data))]

Comment: Can you put the Excel file (at least the relevant records, maybe obfuscating or deleting columns) online?

Comment: Raffaele, here's an example https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18478297/dummydata.xlsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and got around it by not parsing the dates using Pandas, but rather applying my own function (shown below) to the relevant column(s) of the dataframe:

```
def ExcelDateToDateTime(xlDate):
    epoch = dt.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
    delta = dt.timedelta(hours = round(xlDate*24))
    return epoch + delta

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('path')

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(ExcelDateToDateTime)
```

Note: This will ignore any time granularity below the hour level, but that's all I need, and it looks from your example that this could be the case for you too.

Answer (score 2):

Excel serializes datetimes with a `ddddd.tttttt` format, where the `d` part is an integer number representing the offset from a reference day (like Dec 31st, 1899), and the `t` part is a fraction between `0.0` and `1.0` which stands for the part of the day at the given time (for example at 12:00 it's `0.5`, at 18:00 it's `0.75` and so on).

I asked you to upload a file with sample data. `.xlsx` files are really ZIP archives which contains your XML-serialized worksheets. [This are the dates](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/877d7449bd19722b44cb) I extracted from the relevant column. Excerpt:

```
38961.666666666628
38961.708333333292
38961.749999999956
```

When you try to manually deserialize you get the same datetimes as Panda. Unfortunately, the way Excel stores times makes it impossible to represent some values *exactly*, so you have to round them for displaying purposes. I'm not sure if rounded data is needed for analysis, though.

This is the script I used to test that deserialized datetimes are really the same ones as Panda:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, time, timedelta
from urllib2 import urlopen

def deserialize(text):
  tokens = text.split(".")
  date_tok = tokens[0]
  time_tok = tokens[1] if len(tokens) == 2 else "0"
  d = date(1899, 12, 31) + timedelta(int(date_tok))
  t = time(*helper(float("0." + time_tok), (24, 60, 60, 1000000)))
  return datetime.combine(d, t)

def helper(factor, units):
  result = list()
  for unit  in units:
    value, factor = divmod(factor * unit, 1)
    result.append(int(value))
  return result

url = "https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/877d7449bd19722b44cb/raw/" \
      "45d5f0b339d4abf3359fe673fcd2976374ed61b8/dates.txt"

for line in urlopen(url):
  print deserialize(line)
```