# Python import from excel date

Tags: python, pandas

Afternoon,

I have imported some data from excel to pandas using:

```
File = 'C:/Users/Ben/FTSEAXX_Utilities_Price.xlsx'
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(File)
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Price_Data')
```

This has imported correctly, however the date is being displayed differently to the excel input.

excel:

```
Identifier  Company Name    31/12/2009  08/01/2010  15/01/2010  22/01/2010  29/01/2010
```

Python:

```
Identifier  Company Name    2009-12-31 00:00:00 2010-01-08 00:00:00 2010-01-15 00:00:00 2010-01-22 00:00:00 2010-01-29 00:00:00
```

How do i change it to get back to the more simple excel format?

thanks

Ben

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pandas incorrectly reading excel dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874608/python-pandas-incorrectly-reading-excel-dates)

Comment: if the `dtype` is `datetime` then it's just a display issue as it's showing time component and well as the system date format, you can change this to a different string representation but the dtype will change from datetime to str which is probably not what you want

Comment: No its not as the date in effectively the heading for the column and will need to remain in date format when it is exported back to excel. The primary issue is calling each column with pandas